# What does "should" mean in the paragraph? Is it because of grammar rule? Can we omit it? Will the meaning be different?

Tags: should

"Looking back, they appreciate the benefits of the tough times, which made them stronger and *should* enable them to go further in their dancing careers."

Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Here, the should adds emphasis. It implies that it is the responsibility of the benefits acquired from the tough times to enable them to go further.

Omitting the should is not grammatically incorrect.
Without the should, it means that the benefits may or may not play a role in enabling them to go further. The should indicates that the benefits will definitely play a role to help them go further.

Comment: *… which made them stronger and enable them* ***is*** ungrammatical.